# centos mysql log file date format

Tags: mysql, system-administration, logfiles, date-format

i'm sure the answer is obvious but i cannot for the life of me find it. I need to know at what date a specific configuration item changed for my mysqld. This config change is noted in the mysqld.log file of my server, but the date of the entry is formatted like this:

```
120630 11:49:30  mysqld started
```

I need to know the date of this entry, I'm guessing it's the first column, but i cannot figure out how to decode it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT: is, in this case, 120630 supposed to mean June 30th, 2012? I didn't consider this because it doesn't really make sense with the dates in my log file, but i just realized it was possible...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's correct, it's `YYMMDD HH:MM:SS` Which is like a lot of other mysql formats -- at least in terms of date-order. Big to little.

Here's a sample from a dev machine's log from a little over a week ago:

`130520  7:31:51 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events`

It's From May 20th, 2013, at 7:31am.

Comment: Thanks! Although that means i now have to figure out why my logfiles dont make sense :)